# How to change datagridview cells color dinamically

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors

I am trying to change datagridview cells color according his value. I am using the code below:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                int n = item.Index;

    double hsft = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value);
                double asft = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value);
                string ris1 = "1";
                string risX = "X";
                string ris2 = "2";

                if (hsft > asft)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = ris1.ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else if (hsft == asft)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = risX.ToString();
                     dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
                else if (hsft < asft)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = ris2.ToString();
                     dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
}
```

In another project it works but in this case it's not working (but I don't get any error).
What Can I do?

**EDIT:** I edited my code. Check it please

Comment: Does this code run in a certain event? The datagridview control has issues where you can't change the color of cells until it has shown and in some other corner cases, so it would be helpful to know some context around this code.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited the code, it's into a foreach

Comment: But does this fire in a certain event like the datagridview's Formatting event, Shown event, etc? Or maybe in the form constructor, loaded event, etc? What makes the loop run?

Comment: You got the point: if I put this code in a button it works, but I'd like to load it when I launch the program. Where should I put it? maybe form load?

Comment: That would be too soon. The Shown event is a better place. But of cours whenever the data change it must run again.. Another option would be to add the coloring to the CellPainting event.

Comment: Ok, I got the point. At the moment I'll keep it into a button. Thanks